# jQuery click link when another is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element like this

I want `mylink2` to also be clicked whenever somebody clicks on `mylink`

To start I am trying to get the parent container on click like this

```js
 $("#mylink").click(function(){
        parentcontainer =  this.closest('.myelement');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myelement">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="testitem">
                <a id="mylink" href="#">
                    Test Link 1
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <a id="mylink2" href="#">
                Test Link 2
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But now I am stuck trying to click `mylink2` am I on the right track?

Comment: Why not just `$("#mylink2").click();` in your click listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `closest` to get the parent and then `find` second element and trigger `click` command but since you have ids maybe you can use them for selecting elements. Keep in mind that id's must be unique.

```js
$("#mylink").click(function() {
  const parent = $(this).closest('.myelement');
  parent.find('#mylink2').trigger('click')
});

$("#mylink2").on('click', function() {
  console.log('click link 2')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myelement">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="testitem">
      <a id="mylink" href="#">
        Test Link 1
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <a id="mylink2" href="#">
      Test Link 2
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you use the ids, there is no need to get the parent

Answer (score 1):

you can trigger the jQuery first click to trigger the second one this way:

`$("#mylink").click(function(){
    $("#mylink2").click();
});`

taking in cosider that `#mylink2` has some kind of a click handler function

Answer (score 1):

If your links have ids the easiest way would be to use these ids:

```js
$('#mylink').on('click', function(event) {
  console.log('my link click');
  $('#mylink2').click();
});
$('#mylink2').on('click', function(event) {
  console.log('my link2 click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myelement">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="testitem">
            <a id="mylink" href="#">
                Test Link 1
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <a id="mylink2" href="#">
            Test Link 2
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    $('#mylink, #mylink2').on('click', function(event){
        console.log($("#mylink1").text());
        console.log($("#mylink2").text());
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be straightforward since you are using unique IDs for the two elements.
Triggering the second elements click event in the first elements handler.

```
     $("#mylink").on("click", function(){
      $("#mylink2").trigger("click");
     });`
```